# proof for equality of measures for case the case that $F_{\mu}$ be the completion of $F$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,F, \mu)$ be a measure space, and let $F_{\mu}$ be the completion of $F$ relative to $\mu$. If $A \subset \Omega$, define:

$\mu_{0}(A)=\sup \{\mu(B: B \in F, B\subset A \}$,     $\mu^{0}(A)=\inf \{\mu(B: B \in F, B\supset A \}$.

If $A \in F_{\mu}$, show that $\mu_{0}(A)=\mu^{0}(A)=\mu(A)$. Conversely, if $\mu_{0}(A)=\mu^{0}(A)< \infty$, show that $A \in F_{\mu}$.

Based on difinition it is obvios that $\mu_0(A)\leq \mu^0(A)$. However I tried so many ways to proves $μ_0(A)\geq \mu^0(A)$, and I reach nothing.

Comment: @user133281 Based on difinition it is obvios that $\mu_{0}(A) \le \mu ^{0} (A)$. however I tried so many ways to proves $\mu_{0}(A) \ge \mu ^{0} (A)$, and I reach nothing.